# Vue error when I move script in sepparate file

Tags: vue.js

I had a big file .vue which contained script, template and styles. I moved template and styles in sepparate file. But when I moved script in sepparate file there appeared errors.

```
<template src="./MonitoringTree.html"></template>
<style src="./MonitoringTree.less" lang='less'></style>
<script src="./MonitoringTree.ts" lang="ts"></script>
```

Error example:
Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.
799 |         i.parentNodeId

If I understand correctly '$' symbol is about Vue. Not jquery.
Vue version is vue@2.7.7

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. It's unknown what's your case, whether there's $ in code and where the error occurs. If it's in IDE then this is IDE problem. External script files are in grey zone, it's known they have been supported at some point but that's all.